# Cleanup a QString from garbage even if it starts with a null char

Tags: c++, qt, qstring

Using the QtOpcUa library I read a "string" from a PLC. The retrieved data is a `QVariant`:

```
void MyClass::opcua_valueChanged(QString key, QVariant value)
{
    qDebug() << value;
}
```

here a real output:

```
QVariant(QString, "\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u000E@��\u0005���\u0010�M�X���")
```

Since it starts with a `\0` char, I expect it is an empty string.
But if I do something like:

```
QString s = value.toString().trimmed(); 
qDebug() << s;
```

I get:

```
"\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u000E@��\u0005���\u0010�M�X���"
```

instead of: `""`.
What I have to do in order to get the "real" empty string, since it starts with a null char?

Comment: *Since it starts with a \0 char, I expect it is an empty string.* -- I don't use qt, but isn't `QString`'s length determined by something other than a terminating null?  For example, `std::string::size()` is what determines the size of the string, not the terminating null.

Comment: fwiw also `std::string` can contain `\0`s anywhere, it just doesnt play well with any other function that expect a null-terminated string. Seems like `qDebug` doesnt care about the terminator but about the actual lenght of the string

Comment: QString sounds very wrong here. If your data is not UTF-16 text, there's even a good chance of crashing. Use a QByteArray, or `std::vector<uint16_t>` or whatever is correct.

Comment: @hyde it *is* a plain text.

Comment: @Mark What do you mean by "plain text"? For the most common meaning of "plain text" (not "rich text"), that is irrelevant. What is relevant is, is it UTF-16 text. Having only non-printable characters is a strong sign, that there is some encoding mismatch somewhere.

Comment: @hyde I mean in that field I should retrieve a label for a running order. Something like: "COTTON16" or "SILK-32T". When the field is populated I find the content followed by garbage chars. If the field is empty there is a null char and garbage chars like my example.

Comment: @Mark It's just a bit odd to me, that you are receiving UTF-16 text. I'd imagine it would be some 8-bit encoding (UTF-8, Latin1, US-ASCII7, or encodong-agnostic raw bytes even). If there is some garbage chars in _QString_, it means raw data was not correctly decoded into _QString_. Can you access the raw data (QByteArray or char pointer or whatever)?

Answer (score 0):

Based upon the comments received I solved in this way:

```
if (s.startsWith('\0')) s = "";
```

Comment: You need to be careful about this.  Maybe the data you are truncating is important in the functioning of whatever the `QString` will be used for.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I understand your point, but by design if the string starts with `\0` I can safely ignore the other chars. The PLC programmer told me that.